# gdisk MBR and GPT damaged

Tags: mbr, gpt, gdisk

I'm trying to clone my SSD into a bigger one using `CloneZilla`, but I got a problem saying that my disk contains mismatched gpt and mbr partition. I tried the `gdisk` command to see what is wrong in there and I got the following output:

```
:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Warning: Invalid CRC on main header data; loaded backup partition table.
Warning! Main and backup partition tables differ! Use the 'c' and 'e' options
on the recovery & transformation menu to examine the two tables.

Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: ERROR
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: ERROR
Backup partition table: OK

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT
#ANSWER :1 
Your answer: 1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Model: KXG50ZNV256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB         
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E6CFA05B-CA93-4618-A96B-B5DA3798F712
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4717 sectors (2.3 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   5         1052672       500117503   238.0 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
# ANSWER:2
Your answer: 2
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Model: KXG50ZNV256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB         
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 22A0AC92-610F-4098-9FF6-23B0E7B40479
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 500118125 sectors (238.5 GiB)
```

More details about my disk partitions are below:
[image]
[image]

`fdisk` is giving this output:

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: KXG50ZNV256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5b307d3a

Device         Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *       2048   1050623   1048576  512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1052670 500117503 499064834  238G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      1052672 500117503 499064832  238G 83 Linux
```

Not sure exactly what this means or how it can be fixed. Excuse me in advance if this is a naive question. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 269,53 MiB, 282611712 bytes, 551976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 114,101 MiB, 120573952 bytes, 235496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 55,58 MiB, 58261504 bytes, 113792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 269,53 MiB, 282607616 bytes, 551968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 63,23 MiB, 66293760 bytes, 129480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 114,95 MiB, 120508416 bytes, 235368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 55,58 MiB, 58261504 bytes, 113792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: KXG50ZNV256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5b307d3a

Device         Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *       2048   1050623   1048576  512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1052670 500117503 499064834  238G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      1052672 500117503 499064832  238G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sda: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000LM007-1R81
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2ce6dde7

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    1126399    1124352  549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       1126400 3907026943 3905900544  1,8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/loop13: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 164,78 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 521,45 MiB, 546766848 bytes, 1067904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 218,102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 346,34 MiB, 363151360 bytes, 709280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 391,28 MiB, 410279936 bytes, 801328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 346,3 MiB, 363118592 bytes, 709216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 61,98 MiB, 64966656 bytes, 126888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 140 KiB, 143360 bytes, 280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 81,27 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 91,7 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 260,73 MiB, 273375232 bytes, 533936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop20: 424,17 MiB, 444768256 bytes, 868688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop21: 323,52 MiB, 339222528 bytes, 662544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop22: 107,54 MiB, 112746496 bytes, 220208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop23: 107,54 MiB, 112746496 bytes, 220208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop24: 200 KiB, 204800 bytes, 400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop25: 200 KiB, 204800 bytes, 400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop26: 559,71 MiB, 586883072 bytes, 1146256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop27: 559,98 MiB, 587153408 bytes, 1146784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop28: 54,24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop29: 45,95 MiB, 48156672 bytes, 94056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop30: 47,102 MiB, 50323456 bytes, 98288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop31: 47,101 MiB, 50315264 bytes, 98272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop32: 187,48 MiB, 196579328 bytes, 383944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop33: 187,16 MiB, 196251648 bytes, 383304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop34: 295,73 MiB, 310079488 bytes, 605624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop35: 89,48 MiB, 93810688 bytes, 183224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop36: 89,47 MiB, 93802496 bytes, 183208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: It would be helpful to also see the output of `fdisk -l` for the old, smaller SSD. Or is `/dev/nvme0n1` the old, smaller SSD?

Comment: Yep `/dev/nvme0n1` is the smaller SSD I'm currently using. I've edited my question to include what you requested. Thanks.

Comment: It looks as if this disk (`/dev/nvme0n1`) had a GPT partition table and then you cloned a Disk with dos partition table (MBR) to it. This replaced the GPT partition table with the dos partition table but the backup of the GPT partition table which is stored at the very last sectors of the disk has not been overwritten because the origin was smaller than this disk.

Comment: Ok got it. Is there anyway to fix this without formatting the disk? Thanks

Comment: If my assumption was correct, you could overwrite the last 33 sectors of the disk with a command like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of =/dev/nvme0n1 seek=500118142`. Be aware that `dd` is a very dangerous command which can destroy your data on the disk, so backups are recommended, also take a deep look into `man dd`.